# Dealing with highly "unbalanced" regression problems

Tags: regression, machine-learning, neural-networks

I am currently working on a model that estimates hurricane intensities based on satellite images. Naturally, the target variable is highly skewed, i.e. while the mean is around 70-80, a few values can go up to 180. Of course, an accurate estimation is arguably more important for these extreme values, as the potential damage is roughly squared with wind speeds.

I am wondering whether the following approaches are valid:

1. On the training set, randomly draw samples with replacement, where the probability for each sample is inverse to the probability of this label in the whole dataset or
2. Setting the sample_weight to this inverse value when training the neural network
3. Simply do not bother with balancing the targets
4. Implement a custom loss that e.g. multiplies the ground truth with the squared error, leading to a much higher weight of these observations. This would be somewhat similar to 2.

I am pretty sure that for the validation and test set no modifications should be taken.

Any ideas here?